# How to enable opcache in PHP7

Tags: centos7, php-7, opcache

Hi I just installed my PHP7 in a centos7 server. I was wondering if I still need to install Opcache in this server or does it come together with PHP7? If its already bundled how can I enable it? I tried using the below config and restart nginx and php-fpm but no luck

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.enable=1
```

But when I try to search for the file opcache.so there are no results. Does it mean I have to install it? and when I check my phpinfo here's what I get

[image]
[image]